# PATCH request with operator "Remove" not getting sent when removing a member from a group

Tags: azure-active-directory, scim

I am looking into Azure AD SCIM Provisioning and I have a question I am hoping I could get some help on. My use case is as follows

1. I created a Group in Azure AD and added "John Smith" and "Jane Smith" as members to it.
2. I went over to my Non-Gallery application added the Group created above to my application and triggered an On-Demand provisioning.
3. Both "John Smith" and "Jane Smith" were successfully created in my local database.
4. I removed  "John Smith" from my group and triggered an On-Demand provisioning again.
5. My expectation was that the following PATCH request would be sent by Azure Ad

```
"Operations": [
{
  "op": "Remove",
  "path": "members",
  "value": "john-smith-id"
}
]
```

but instead Azure AD sends a PATCH request to /Users with the following body

```
"schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp"
    ],
    "Operations": [
        {
            "op": "Add",
            "path": "displayName",
            "value": "John Smith"
        }
    ]
```

and another PATCH request to /Groups with the following body

```
"schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp"
    ],
    "Operations": [
        {
            "op": "Add",
            "path": "externalId",
            "value": "some-guid"
        }
    ]
```

Is this correct? I feel like I am messing something up when removing the member from the Group which isn't triggering the desired PATCH request

Comment: This only seems to appear during "On Demand Provisioning", The desired PATCH request is sent when provisioning occurs every 40 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

After step #4, I would recommend checking if the user has successfully been removed from the group.

Also, make sure that you're using the right rule ID in the on-demand provisioning request. One easy way to do this is to try through the UI and look at the network traffic ctrl+shift+i

The rule ID can be found in the schema.

Comment: I did double check and "John Smith" no longer exists in the Group. As for the ruleID I am not entirely sure on that. I am using `ngrok` to create a tunnel and Azure AD is communicating to my localhost webApi via this tunnel.

Comment: If you do a GET schema call, you can also get the ID. It's the first property in the response in the sycnhronizationRules object. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/synchronization-synchronizationschema-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Comment: Is the rule ID something I need to set in Azure AD or account for in my application. I do see it in my network trace just wondering how I can use it. Thank you

Comment: You don't need to set the ruleID in Azure AD. It is automatically generated when you create the provisioning job. You'll need to make sure to use the correct ruleID that you retrieve from the provisioning job schema.